# Pseudo active class not working in scss file

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, navigation

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6RzY.png)

> This is my simple header of navigation and logo

```
 <header>
    <div class="logo" style="width: 11%;">
        <img src="Images/logo.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
</header>
```

> My CSS in which active class is not working while others are working well

```
     li
        {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 18px;      
          
            a
              {
                display: inline-block;
                color:$secondary;
                padding: 17px;

                &:active
                 {
                     padding: 10px; 
                     background : blue;
                     font-weight: bold;
                 } 
               }
                             
         }
```

> Whether you use hover or focus it will work but active pseudo class is not in progress
> can anyone help

Comment: That $secondary is a variable i made for the color

Comment: It is working as expected.

Comment: No its not
you can see on the picture above

Comment: The code you posted in your question is working. see here https://imgur.com/TBWKvpv

Comment: i think browser dont want me to work

Comment: XDDD check for typo in your original code

Answer (score 0):

Your confused between pseudo-classes and CSS classes what you need here is a CSS class to be set on the active list item and to do that you need to add some JS

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
    });
}
```

```css
 li{
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 18px;      
      a
      {
        display: inline-block;
        color: gray;
        padding: 17px;
      }
                             
  }
.active{
    padding: 10px; 
    background : blue;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
 <header>
    <div class="logo" style="width: 11%;">
        <img src="Images/logo.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul id="myDIV">
            <li class="li active">
                <a href="#" >HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li">
                <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li">
                <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li">
                <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li">
                <a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li">
                <a href="#">FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li">
                <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
</header>
```